# Troubleshooting function to calculate derivative of kth coordinate

Tags: r, function

I am trying to write a function that will take a matrix of coordinates, p,  and a positive whole number, k, and return the partial derivative of E (which I will give later) with respect to the kth coordinate.

I am trying to model the energy of a configuration of m molecules. Each molecule j has position [image: coordinate]
<sub>(source: [rogercortesi.com](http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/tempimagedir/eqn5356.png))</sub>
. [image: r]
<sub>(source: [rogercortesi.com](http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/tempimagedir/eqn1000.png))</sub>
 is the distance between molecules i and j: [image: distance]
<sub>(source: [rogercortesi.com](http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/tempimagedir/eqn6737.png))</sub>

[image: U]
<sub>(source: [rogercortesi.com](http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/tempimagedir/eqn8027.png))</sub>

[image: sum]
<sub>(source: [rogercortesi.com](http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/tempimagedir/eqn4293.png))</sub>

I found that the partial derivative of E with respect to [image: x1]
<sub>(source: [rogercortesi.com](http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/tempimagedir/eqn6885.png))</sub>
 is [image: sum2]
<sub>(source: [rogercortesi.com](http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/tempimagedir/eqn2003.png))</sub>
, which can be generalized for the partial derivatives of all other variables.

p is a mx3 matrix where each row contains a coordinate. We want to find the partial derivative of the kth coordinate, where [image: k]
<sub>(source: [rogercortesi.com](http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/tempimagedir/eqn7008.png))</sub>

I believe that the function below should be able to take p and k and calculate the partial derivative of E with respect to the kth coordinate.

```
partial <- function(p,k){
   m <- dim(p)
   m <- m[1]
   m <- as.numeric(m)
   d1 <- k%/%3+1
   d2 <- ifelse (k%%3 == 0, 3, k%%3)
   distance = function(a,b){
       r <- sqrt((p[a,1]-p[b,1])^2+(p[a,2]-p[b,2])^2+(p[a,3]-p[b,3])^2)
       return(r)
   }
   sum <- 0
   for(j in 1:m){
       sum <- sum + (p[d1,d2]-p[j,d2])*(distance(d1,j)^(-8)-distance(d1,j)^(-14))
   }
   sum <- 12*sum
   return(sum)
}
```

However, when I test the function out with the following:

```
coordinates <- matrix(c(0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0),nrow=3,byrow=T)
partial (coordinates,7)
```

I just get "NaN", which I don't believe should be the case. What am I doing wrong? I'd appreciate any guidance. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I find it's helpful to save `p=c(0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0)` and `k=7` and then walk through the code in the function line by line. With this simple debugging, you'll find that the problem lies in one of the calls to `distance(d1,j)^(-8)`, in particular when the distance is zero as Brad points out in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, when j=3=d1, distance(d1,j) is zero.

Comment: Just found the same thing. Just to add on to this, 0 with a negative exponent is calculated as `Inf` (Infinity). The loop then does `0*Inf` which gives you `NaN`.